# android-arch,livedata,can't receive apiResponse call result listening by result observer of fetchFromNetWork method in NetworkBounResource class

Tags: java, android

Why can't I receive apiResponse call result listening by result observer of fetchFromNetWork method in NetworkBounResource class,

for example:

```
private void fetchFromNetwork(final LiveData<ResultType> dbSource) {
    LiveData<ApiResponse<RequestType>> apiResponse = createCall();
    result.addSource(apiResponse, new Observer<ApiResponse<RequestType>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable ApiResponse<RequestType> requestTypeApiResponse) {
        //Question?? can't go into here
            if(requestTypeApiResponse.isSuccessful())
            {
                String success="";
            }else
            {

            }
        }
   });
}
```

remark: I debug my code,the apiResponse has execute call.enqueue and has the reponse value,such as:

```
@Override
protected void onActive() {
    super.onActive();
    if (started.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
        call.enqueue(new Callback<R>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<R> call, Response<R> response) {
            //has got the response data
                postValue(new ApiResponse<>(response));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<R> call, Throwable throwable) {
                postValue(new ApiResponse<R>(throwable));
            }
        });
    }
}
```